# R tree bounding box structure visualization tool

Tags: tree, visualization, geospatial, bounding-box, r-tree

What kind of tool can i use to visualize the bounding boxes, nodes, leaves of a R tree, like the ones shown on this page? Thank you

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/spatial_indexes/introduction.html

Comment: I have used R*-Trees in ELKI and it has an easy to use option to visualize them. But for anything but tiny data sets, it becomes too complicated.

Comment: That is because of the tree. Such a visualization is nice if you have only 2 levels with 4 pages each. A real tree will have a fanout of 100 and 3-4 levels, so you will have an insane amount of rectangles on your screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These particular images were generated with this program using GLUT library:

BOOST_ROOT/libs/geometry/index/example/glut_vis.cpp

or

https://github.com/boostorg/geometry/blob/develop/index/example/glut_vis.cpp

It uses a utility function hidden in the details `boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::utilities::gl_draw()` to draw Boost.Geometry `rtree<>` using OpenGL. It can be found here:

BOOST_ROOT/boost/geometry/index/detail/rtree/utilities/gl_draw.hpp

or

https://github.com/boostorg/geometry/blob/develop/include/boost/geometry/index/detail/rtree/utilities/gl_draw.hpp

Answer (score 0):

Here is a web gui visualizer tool for R-Tree bounding boxes. It supports Rectangular bounding boxes as well as circular bounding boxes. It supports manual entry of leaves or random generation.

https://www.johnfoxweb.com/personalWebsite/html/academicProjects/regions.html